# On an HTC Evo, is there any way to sync only 'my contacts' from gmail (not 'all contacts')?

Tags: contacts, sync, htc-evo, gmail

I've seen references to this posted elsewhere, but never a solution. I'd like to only sync the "my contacts" group of contacts from my gmail (really google apps, but should work the same) account, rather than "all contacts". I can not find an option to change this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I like to sync all contacts and then in contact list I choose to only show the ones with phone numbers. To do this open Contacts > menu > View > select "Contacts with phone numbers". Not sure if that is what you are looking for but is the only thing I could find for a solution on Evo.

Strange, the directions below will work on other Android devices, but not an HTC Sense devices.

Open contacts > menu > Settings > Edit sync groups. Select "Sync all contacts", "My Contacts" or "Starred in Android".

For HTC sense do the following, contacts (people) > Groups tab > menu > Sync Groups.

Note, on my Evo neither option worked for me. I'm running 2.2 and suspect that is part of the reason.

Comment: I am using the option to only sync contacts with phone numbers, but I'd still like to prevent it from syncing all of my gmail contacts.  I like having peoples' contact information available in gmail, but don't want everyone I correspond with to be synced to my phone. This is a pretty frustrating shortcoming, especially considering it's just a matter of a Google product interacting correctly with another Google product.

Comment: Are you rooted?

Comment: It is possible to do if rooted by either running an ASOP ROM or by installing the ASOP contacts apk. But it looks like that is the only way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

So this is a complete workaround, but worked for me and I'll keep it this way until there's a better solution.  It's a real pain to have contacts updating each time you send an email to someone.  I for instance, sell items on craigslist occasionally and in a 5 day period got and replied to over 60 people, most of them offering some sort of offshore job offer scam.....yet they all go in my EVO 4G contacts!  Irritating for sure.

What I did was this, it took me a half an hour:

Set up a New Account Group in Google called Temporary (name is irrelevant)
Moved all of the contacts that I didn't want on my phone into this group
Deleted all of them
Deleted the group altogether

Then I set my Auto-Sync settings on my handset for contact-syncs to Manual.

So now, I have only the contacts I want on my phone.  Not sure how this will play out once I want to add contacts, but for now my contact book is very clean and tidy.

Comment: With Gmail, at least, you can turn off the setting whereby every person you send an e-mail message to ends up in your contacts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the Evo uses the vanilla contacts and dialing app, but if it does, it's a two step process.  First, you have to organize your contacts into groups in GMail.  Adding a star to any contact on your phone will add it to the "Stared in Android" contact group in GMail.  This will be principally for contacts that you wish to sync, but don't feel like putting into another group.  For me, these are mainly the phone numbers of local taxi companies.  Now, on your phone, open your contacts, hit the menu button, and select Display Options, expand the google contacts, and then start deselecting groups, especially All Other Contacts.  All Other Contacts include all the contacts that are in My Contacts (added liberally by GMail) but aren't in any groups.