# Sprint HTC shift: delete all gmail contacts with no phone number

Tags: contacts, gmail

After syncing my phone with a gmail account, all of my gmail contacts were loaded onto my phone... Now any app that pulls all my phone's contacts, such as RingDroid, will include hundreds of email addies I don't care about at all. Is there any way to wipe all these no-phonenumber email contacts?
Unsyncing is not a solution, the contacts remain. And please don't tell me to revert my phone to factory settings over something so rudimentary as this.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/920/on-an-htc-evo-is-there-any-way-to-sync-only-my-contacts-from-gmail-not-all-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the "People" application and press the menu key, and then "view" and click "only contacts with phone numbers"

Comment: This unfortunately still seems to leave email contacts on the phone. You could say it's the fault of the app for pulling that info, but it's only doing so because the info is on my phone somewhere..

Comment: Ah, now I think I understand. Do you by chance have "auto gmail contacts" checked in that same menu? If you have "only contacts with phone numbers" checked and "auto gmail contacts" unchecked, the expected behavior is that you would only have "real" contacts (contacts you created) from gmail. Also, if you remove a contact are they being removed from ringdroid (I don't use it, I had all my ringtones edited down in audacity)? If not, then I recommend removing the app, editing your contact list, then reinstalling.